# BlockUI java script not execting inside of ContentPlacehoder of aspx page Master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have the following BlockUI javascript set up to run on an aspx page which is in a ContentPlaceholder of a Master page. When the page loads and when I click the ASP button, the javascript fires, and shows the alert boxes 1 and 4, but not 2 and 3.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('alert1');

    $('#Button3').click(function() {
    alert('alert2 button clicked');
        $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Just a moment...</h1>' });

        alert('alert 3 It clicked!');
    });
    alert('alert4!');
 });

 </script>
```

I am think it has something to do with finding the button inside of the ContentPlaceholder.

Any Ideas anyone?

Here's the button, no code behind events are set up on it.

```
 <td class="style17">
     <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change selector from `$('#Button3')` to `$('#<%= Button3.ClientID %>')`

By the way, if you want to prevent postback on this button click you must add `OnClientClick="return false;"` to this button

Comment: Well this is a test I am trying to get working. I am hoping to attach the block to an Edit click event on a Gridview that currently opens an aspx popup page and then Unblock on submit from the Popup.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Yuriy's answer:  The ID field in an ASP.NET control gets altered before it is rendered as html.  It'll actually come out as something like "ctl00_contentGuts_FORMNAME___CONTAINER_FIELD" or something similar.  This helps ASP.NET identify it, especially when used within list controls.

Yuriy's answer of changing the selector to `$('#<%= Button3.ClientID %>')`  should work fine.  ASP.NET's rendering engine will see the <%= > part, and render it using the Button's client id.

Now, what version of .NET are you using?  I ask because in .NET 4 there is a cleaner way.  In .NET 4 you can set a ClientID attribute on the control, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" ClientID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

This will ensure that you know the button ID, and is a little cleaner and easier to read than the other method.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, still at 3.5..............How would I go about getting an Edit click event on gridview to execute the java script.